# How to fix the following exception opening a simple txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Hello I am trying with jupyter, I installed pandas, python and jupyter,
In order to check if everything is ok I tried to open a txt file using pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_csv("/authorprof/res_es.txt", sep=" ", header = None)
```

the txt file looks as follows:

```
Running testing authorid
Running training authorprof
[[325 301]
 [236 191]
 [294 274]
 [354 357]
 [237 241]
 [344 335]
 [419 401]
 [312 286]
 [209 206]
```

however I am getting the following exception:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CParserError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-c970702c41ed> in <module>()
      3 print(sys.version)
      4 print(pd.__version__)
----> 5 df=pd.read_csv("/authorprof/res_es.txt", sep=" ", header = None)
      6 
      7 

/home/neo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    561 
--> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    563 
    564     parser_f.__name__ = name

/home/neo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    323         return parser
    324 
--> 325     return parser.read()
    326 
    327 _parser_defaults = {

/home/neo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
    813                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
    814 
--> 815         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
    816 
    817         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/home/neo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1312     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1313         try:
-> 1314             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1315         except StopIteration:
   1316             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:8748)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:9003)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9731)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:9602)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:23325)()

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 71, saw 5
```

I hope someone tell me why?, I am getting that exception, I am a beginner using jupyter notebook, I believe that maybe is a kind of bug I printed my python version and pandas version to add more details:

```
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
0.18.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need parameter `skiprows` for omit first 2 rows in `txt`:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/authorprof/res_es.txt", sep="s\+", header = None, skiprows=2)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Running testing authorid
Running training authorprof
[[325 301]
 [236 191]
 [294 274]
 [354 357]
 [237 241]
 [344 335]
 [419 401]
 [312 286]
 [209 206]"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),  delim_whitespace=True, header = None, skiprows=2)

print (df)
       0     1
0  [[325  301]
1   [236  191]
2   [294  274]
3   [354  357]
4   [237  241]
5   [344  335]
6   [419  401]
7   [312  286]
8   [209  206]
```

Comment: Thanks for the support but I am getting the same error:----> 5 df=pd.read_csv("/authorprof/res_es.txt", sep=" ", header = None, skiprows=2)/home/neo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format,

Comment: my data has not a defined structure it contains things like: feats/spanish/user759.txt
[u'00', u'000', u'10', u'100', u'11', u'12', u'13', u'14', u'15', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20', u'2011', do you know if pandas is able to read things like this? maybe this is the root of the issue,

Comment: Ok, I think the best is share your file if not confidental in gdocs, dropbox, wetrasfer. Or send me email (in my profile)

Comment: ok this was just a testing I already understood that when the txt has not a defined structure, it generates errors while is read, thanks for the support, I will accept your answer was very useful,